# Families of Fano varieties over non-hyperbolic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, moduli-spaces, fano-varieties

Let $C$ be a non-hyperbolic (smooth quasi-projective connected complex algebraic) curve. That is, $C$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb P^1, \mathbb A^1, \mathbb G_m$, or an elliptic curve.

Let $f:X\to C$ be a family of Fano varieties, i.e., $f$ is a smooth projective morphism whose geometric fibres are (smooth projective connected) Fano varieties. (Fano means anti-canonical bundle ample.)

Is $f$ isotrivial? In other words, are all the fibres of $f$ isomorphic?

**Note.** A family $f:X\to C$ of varieties with semi-ample canonical bundle is isotrivial. This follows from the work of Campana, Kebekus, Kovacs, Lieblich, Viehweg, Zuo, et al.

**Note.** If $f$ is non-isotrivial, the relative dimension of $f$ will have to be at least three.

**Motivation.** I think it is reasonable to suspect that certain connected components of the stack of Fano varieties   have only finitely many  integral points over $\mathbb Z$. If this expectation holds any family of Fano varieties $f:X\to C$, where $C$ is a non-hyperbolic curve, is isotrivial over $C$.

Comment: Even though you specify "complex", I want to point out that these are fairly easy to find in positive characteristic, e.g., using the pencil of plane curves that I describe [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/115361/when-is-the-kernel-of-the-etale-fundamental-group-in-a-fibration-abelian/115498#115498).  You can consider $[u,v,w]=[1,1,1]$ as a point $p$ on those curves, and then you can take the moduli space of rank $r$ bundles whose determinant is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_C(p)$.

Comment: hyperbolicity properties of moduli spaces and the existence
of non-isotrivial families in the sense of the hyperbolicity conjecture
of $ {Shafarevich}$ correspond to semi-positivity of relative canonical bundle $K_{X/C}$ , in fact if the fibers are K-stable Fano varieties then it corresponds to semi-positivity of fiberwise Kahler-Einstein metric (such relative Kahler metrics are not positive or closed in general)

Comment: To understand more about my previous comment see my comments here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/284809/symplectic-form-on-an-algebraic-family#comment703555_284809 . My conjecture is that semi-positivity of such fiberwise Kahler-Einstein metric is corresponds the relative tangent sheaf $(T_{X/C})^{**}$ be stable in he sense of Mumford.

Comment: Another way to attack this problem is to break it up to rigidity+Hyperbolicity+boundedness of degree of direct image of relative canonical divisor see http://www.crm.umontreal.ca/Holomorphes07/pdf/viehwegslides.pdf http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.589.559&rep=rep1&type=pdf and https://sites.math.washington.edu/~kovacs/2013/papers/Kovacs__Strong_non-isotriviality_and_rigidity.pdf and https://sites.math.washington.edu/~kovacs/2013/papers/Kovacs__Subvarieties_of_moduli_stacks.pdf

Comment: From Ricci flow approach the hyperbolicity conjecture of Shafarevich about the existence of non-isotrivial family corresponds to convergence of the relative Kahler Ricci flow and $C^0$-estimate and solutions remain semi-positive. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.05465.pdf . In fact, this is the right flow to give an effective way for the conjecture of Griffiths (in this case the total space we need to take $\mathbb P(E)$). In fact, Ricci flow resolves the singularities by one time $t$, but in relative Kahler-Ricci flow, we have two times $s$ and $t$. where $t\to \infty$ and $s\to 0$,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $X = SO(10)/P_5 \subset P^{15}$ be the spinor variety. It is projectively self-dual and has codimension 5, so its generic linear section of codimension 5 is smooth, and, moreover, generic pencil of codimension 4 is smooth. On the other hand, sections of codimension 4 are parameterized by $Gr(4,16)$ which has dimension 48, while the group of automorpisms of $X$ is $SO(10)$ and so has dimension 45. So, I guess that a generic pencil of linear sections of $X$ of codimension 4 is an example of a nonisotrivial family.

EDIT --- MORE DETAILS. The Fano varieties one gets in this way are 6-folds of index 4 and degree 12. Their Hodge diamond is diagonal and the diagonal Hodge numbers are $(1,1,1,2,1,1,1)$. They are Fano just by the adjunction formula.

Comment: Are you able to provide further details for how your construction works? For example, what are the Fano varieties in your construction, the intersection of $X$ with a linear subspace of $\mathbb{P}^{15}$ of codimension $4$? Why are these Fano?

Comment: @Daniel: I added some details. If you want to know something else I will be happy to tell you.

Comment: I am a bit skeptical.  By my computation, for a pencil of codimension $q$ linear sections that contains (at most) finitely many singular members, the number of singular members equals the degree in $A_0(X)$ of the cycle class $c_1(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{15}}(1)|_X)^{q-1}c_{11-q}(\Omega_X(1)) + c_1(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{15}}(1)|_X)^{q}c_{10-q}(\Omega_X(1))$.  Of course, since $X$ is homogeneous, we can compute this explicitly.  Although I have not done the computation, I see no a priori reason that the degree should be zero.

Comment: @Jason: The reason is the large codimension of the projectively dual variety. E.g. if you take $q = 1$ then your formula should give the degree of the dual variety, if it is a hypersurface, or zero, if it has larger codimension.

Comment: @Sasha:  Now I see.  I did not get the "projectively self-dual until now".

Comment: @Sasha So this gives a smooth projective non-isotrivial family of Fano sixfolds over $\mathbb P^1$ , right?

Comment: @Ari: I think yes, but to be on the safe side one should check that the family is not isotrivial. For this it is enough to check that the Kodaira-Spencer morphism from the tangent space of $Gr(4,16)$ to $H^1(T_Y)$ is nonzero, where $Y = X \cap P^{11}$.

Comment: @Sasha is this example birationally isotrivial?

Comment: @BenC: Yes, all varieties in this example are rational.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you ask for minimal Fano, this is false. Take a rational curve $C$ on a Fano manifold $M$ (say, del Pezzo surface), and consider a family of blow-ups of $M$ parametrized by $C$, obtained by blowing up a point in $C$. A blow-up is often Fano, but this family is not always isotrivial (say, for an appropriate choice of del Pezzo $M$).

Update: for del Pezzo this argument does not work - sorry!

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced by this argument. There could be some points on $C$ which when blown-up do not yield a Fano variety, for example $C$ could be a curve on a del Pezzo surface which intersects some exceptional curves. In which case the family of Fano varieties would be over a punctured curve, which could quite possibly hyperbolic. Are you able to construct examples which avoid this phenomenon?

Comment: you are right, for del Pezzo this argument does not work! Any such $C$ will meet a quadric passing through the points which are blown up, hence one of its points is not in general position. My apologies.